# IOS textFieldDidBeginEditing

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I'm looking for a little help with an extension I'm trying to use, its a login page that gives out an error through my statusLabel.text, for example if they type an incorrect password the statusLabel.text would show "Email incorrect please try again"

This is my logon section

```
@IBAction func login(_ sender: Any) {

    self.userName.resignFirstResponder()
    self.password.resignFirstResponder()
    self.repeatPassword.resignFirstResponder()
    self.passwordsStack.resignFirstResponder()


    self.progress.startAnimating()
    switch self.currentLoginType {

    case .login:

        let email = self.userName.text
        let password = self.password.text

        FirebaseManager.login(email: email!, password: password!, completion: { (status: Bool, error: Error?) in

            if status && error == nil {
                if FirebaseManager.isEmailVerified {

                    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                    print (error?.localizedDescription ?? "")

                    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                    let LoginVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ReavealVC") as! SWRevealViewController
                    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
                    appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = LoginVC

                } else {

                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.statusLabel.text = "Your email is not verified. Please check your email"
                        self.progress.stopAnimating()
                        print ("have we stopped at email not verified")
                        self.clearLoginTextFields()
                    }
                }
            } else {

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.progress.stopAnimating()
                    self.statusLabel.text = FirebaseManager.StringFromError(error: error)
                    print("have we stopped at email after its not verified")
                    self.clearLoginTextFields()
                }

            }

        })


    case .signup:

        if self.password.text == self.repeatPassword.text{

            let email = self.userName.text
            let password = self.password.text

            FirebaseManager.LinkWithEmailAndPassword(email: email!, password: password!, completion: { (status: Bool, error: Error?) in

                if status && error == nil {

                    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

                    self.progress.stopAnimating()
                    self.statusLabel.text = "Email verification sent, please check you inbox"
                    print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "")

                } else {

                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.progress.stopAnimating()
                        self.statusLabel.text = FirebaseManager.StringFromError(error: error)

                    }
                }
            })
            self.view.endEditing(true)
            clearLoginTextFields()

        }else{
            self.progress.stopAnimating()
            self.statusLabel.text = "Passwords do not match, please try again!"
        }

    case .forgotPassword:

        FirebaseManager.sendPasswordReset(email: self.userName.text!, completion: { (status:Bool) in

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.progress.stopAnimating()
                self.statusLabel.text = status ? "Reset password sent" : "Error sending reset password"
            }
        })

        break
    }

}
```

And my extension

```
extension LoginViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {

    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

        return true
    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

        textField.resignFirstResponder()

        return true
    }

    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {

        textField.resignFirstResponder()

    }

    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {

        statusLabel.text = ""
    }
}
```

I would like the status label to revert back to "" once the user starts to input their credentials again but it looks like my textFieldDidBeginEditing is not being called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the delegate of your UITextFields.

```
userName.delegate = self
password.delegate = self
```

Where I assume that both text fields are located in the LoginViewController.

Besides this approach you could go without the delegate stuff and do:

```
userName.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textChanged(_:)), for: .editingChanged)
```

and

```
func textChanged(textField: UITextField) {

}
```

And you would probably need to check if the message: "Email incorrect please try again" is shown before you set the "".